# PHP/WordPress search query issue

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I'm not very familiar with Wordpress and I'm not sure why my Search Query isn't working.

I have posts that are paginated and displayed accordingly. I have a search bar that should filter the posts based on the search text parameter, but it's not working.

This is how I get my posts:

I made an $args variable and then I'm passing it the $wp_query (I'm not sure if that's even how it's supposed to be done?):

```
$args = [
'post_type' => 'news-post',
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'ASC',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'paged' => $paged,  
's' => $_GET['search'],     
'tax_query' => [] 
];
        
        
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Then my submit form looks like this:

```
<form action="#results">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" value="<?= esc_attr($_GET['search']) ?>">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Currently, the posts are displayed and paginated correctly however the search form seems to do nothing. It only adds "?#results" to the end of the URL and doesn't change the current posts being displayed..

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. My input form needed:

```
name="search"
```